# MacBook Pro 2019 with touchbar freezes chrome forms

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, google-chrome, touch-bar

I have a brand new macbook (2019 with touchbar running macOS Catalina).
When I use an external keyboard all is fine.
But when using the laptop keyboard it is extremely slow/laggy on all website input fields and forms (using chrome).
After the first char it freezes and then maybe 10 seconds later the rest I typed is visible.
On safari it is working normally. I have tried disabling the touchbar, but that does not seem possible. Putting it in F1-F12 mode (not providing suggestions) does not help.
Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure chrome is updated! You can check your version here: `chrome://settings/help`
As @Udhy pointed out in the comment.